# Printing another page with data from a search via ajax connected to the PHP server

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have this jQuery function:

```
function findProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.php",
        data: {
            city: $(".city").val(),
            product: $("#product").val(),
        },
    }).done(function(data) {
        window.location.href = "results.html";
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        obj.forEach(function(index) {
            var tableBody = $("tbody");
            var row = $("<tr>");

            var columnImgName = $("<td>").addClass("img-name");
            var divImg = $("<div>").addClass("image");
            var image = $("<img>").addClass("image-product").attr("src", "img/no-image.png");
            var nameProduct = $("<p>").addClass("name-product").index[0]);

            var columnPrice = $("<td>").addClass("prico").index[1]);

            var rows = tableBody.append(row);

            rows.append(columnImgName).append(divImg).append(image);
            rows.append(columnImgName).append(nameProduct);
            rows.append(columnPrice);
        });
    });
}
```

I'm trying to run a search on my database informing the city and the product. I'm making an ajax to the php code on my server that returns a JSON with the data I searched. I want to get that data that is returned on this JSON and go to another page where I will print a table with the informations I got. I tried this code but it isn't working, it just redirects to the other page but the table doesn't appear. The HTML code for the table is this:

```
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = "results.html";` will redirect and rest code will be kind of useless. Instead create a new page to print and design it however you like and direct POST through it.

Comment: When I make a reference to the page index.html, where this code runs, I received a message on the console saying that the method only works for requisitions for addresses with protocols (like http). I'm not going to upload it to a server, I'm trying to do it in a Cordova application, so there's no protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able do it by putting an action to the form, that would take me to the page `results.html` and also putting on the form the method get.

On the page results, I imported the following jQuery code, to get the data from the URI and run the search on my database

```
var qs = (function(a) {

if (a == "") return {};

var b = {};

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {

    var p=a[i].split('=', 2);

    if (p.length == 1) {

        b[p[0]] = "";
    } else {

        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
}

return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));

var city = qs["city"];
var product = qs["product"];

function findProducts() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "code.php",
        data: {
            city: city,
            product: product,
        },
    }).done(function(data) {

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        obj.forEach(function(index) {

            var name = index[0];
            var price = index[1];

            var bodyTable = $("body").find("tbody");
            var row = makeRows(name, price);

            bodyTable.append(row);
        });
    });
}

function makeRows(name, price) {

    var row = $("<tr>");

    var columnImgName = $("<td>").addClass("img-name");
    var divImg = $("<div>").addClass("image");
    var image = $("<img>").addClass("image-product").attr("src", "img/no-image.png");
    var nameProduct = $("<p>").addClass("name-product").text(name);

    divImg.append(image);
    columnImgName.append(divImg);
    columnImgName.append(nameProduct);

    var columnPrice = $("<td>").addClass("price").text(price);

    row.append(columnImgName);
    row.append(columnPrice);

    return row;
}

findProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
show your data on same page by using bootstrap datatable
Include all necessary js and bootstrap 
View
<table id="table_id1" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd" class="table table-advanced table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead class="blue">
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php                                       
            foreach($Data as $row) {    
        ?>  
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td class="center"><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
        </tr> 
        <?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>


$("#search_button").click(function() {
        $.post("code.php",{"city": $('#city').val(),"product": $('#product').val()},function(data){
            tableid="table_id";
            update_dataTable(data,tableid);
        },'json');
});

function update_dataTable(data,tableid) {

    var oTable = $("#"+tableid).dataTable();
    oTable.fnClearTable();

    $(data).each(function(index) {  
        var row = [];


        row.push(data[index].product);
        row.push(data[index].price);

        oTable.fnAddData(row);
    });
}

show your data on same page by using bootstrap datatable
```

Comment: I'm already using another framework and I can't use php on the html, I'm making it for a Cordova app. And I really need to display the data on another page